# React - catch error - problem with console.log

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, catch2

I have small problem, but I don't know what I doing wrong. I have function like below. In .catch alert working ok and I see error in browser, but I have problem with this same error in console.log <- I don't see anything   Basically, I wanted to pass error to another function like notify(error) but I don't see anything.

```
 const signIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then(() => {
        navigate("/");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // notify(error)
        console.log("error: ", error);
        alert(error);
      });
  };
```

I try doing try catch and async await but I have the same problem:

```
async function signIn(e) {
try {
  e.preventDefault();
  await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(() => {
    navigate("/");
  });
} catch (error) {
  // notify(error);
  console.error("error: ", error);
  alert(err);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the code for notify function?

Answer (score 0):

You can not call error object directly in console.log as js has some issues parsing error as a JSON object. Instead, use `error.message` or `error.toString()` in `notify()` function. Error object has breaks that cause issues when parsing to a JSON object.
Check below code, only `error.message` that is the first line (key : value pair) of the object is accessible. Notice that `JSON.parse(error)` gives an error because of this.

```js
try {
  const a = s.getElementbyId('ss');
  console.log(a.style);
} catch (error) {
  console.log( error.toString());
  console.log(error.message);
  console.log(error.lineno);
  console.log(JSON.parse(error));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing could be related to the error object being passed to the console.log statement. **Sometimes, the error object may not be displayed directly in the console, depending on its structure**.

To ensure that the error is logged properly, you can try using console.error instead of console.log:

```
console.error("error:", error);
```

Additionally, if you want to pass the error to another function like notify, you can **un-comment the notify(error)** line and make sure that the notify function is correctly implemented and able to handle the error object.

```
.catch((error) => {
  notify(error);
  console.error("error:", error);
  alert(error);
});
```